# Double serialization with JSON using Spring and Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, dto

I've decided to use DTOs for all of my entities so I don't have to use @JSONIgnore annotation to ignore some fragile data like ID, password for User etc. in JSONs. I'm not sure if it's the right approach but I couldn't think of anything else - if you happen to know better way to do it just let me know.

But to the point, I have Book entity which has a price among the other fields - it's the only field I want to change in the future, title/isbn etc. don't change (I know it's they are not immutable but it's becasue of JPA - it needs setters/getters/non final fields, right? )

**Book.java** (getters/setters ommited):

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "book_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "isbn", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String isbn;
  @Column(name = "title", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String title;
  @Column(name = "author", nullable = false)
  private String author;
  @Column(name = "genre", nullable = false)
  private String genre;
  @Column(name = "publication_year")
  private Short publicationYear;
  @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
  private BigDecimal price;

  // jpa requirement
  public Book() {
  }
```

And I decided to create BookDTO so I don't have to send ID when I post a new book (so Jackson can deserialize my JSON without complaining).

```
 public class BookDTO {

  // TODO: 01.03.17 Use more specified constraints
  @NotEmpty(message = "ISBN cannot be empty")
  private String isbn;
  @NotEmpty(message = "Title cannot be empty")
  private String title;
  @NotEmpty(message = "Author cannot be empty")
  private String author;
  @NotEmpty(message = "Genre cannot be empty")
  private String genre;
  private Short publicationYear;

  @Digits(integer = 6, fraction = 2, message = "Price must have at most 6 digits and 2 decimals")
  private BigDecimal price;

  public BookDTO(String isbn, String title, String author, String genre,
      String publicationYear, double price) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.publicationYear = Short.valueOf(publicationYear);
    this.price = BigDecimal.valueOf(price);
  }
```

So I store the price as BigDecimal but thought that I could use double in JSON and then just use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double newPrice)` to change the price of Book entity.

Here is my **BookController.java**:

```
@RestController
public class BookController {
  private final BookService bookService;

  @Autowired
  public BookController(BookService bookService) {
    this.bookService = bookService;
  }

  @PutMapping("/books/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<?> editToDo(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody double newPrice) 
      return new ResponseEntity<>(bookService.changePrice(id, newPrice), HttpStatus.OK);
      }
```

And my **BookService.java**:

```
   @Service
@Transactional
public class BookService {

  private final BookRepository bookRepository;

  @Autowired
  public BookService(BookRepository bookRepository) {
    this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
  }

  public Book addNewBook(BookDTO bookDTO) {
    if (bookRepository.findByIsbn(bookDTO.getIsbn()).isPresent()) {
      throw new BookException(
          String.format("Book with that ISBN already exists in database: %s", bookDTO.getIsbn()));
    }
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setAuthor(bookDTO.getAuthor());
    book.setGenre(bookDTO.getGenre());
    book.setIsbn(bookDTO.getIsbn());
    book.setPrice(bookDTO.getPrice());
    book.setPublicationYear(bookDTO.getPublicationYear());
    book.setTitle(bookDTO.getTitle());
    return bookRepository.save(book);
  }

  public Book changePrice(Long id, double price) {
    Book book = findBookById(id);
    book.setPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(price));
    return book;
  }

  public void deleteBook(Long id) {
    bookRepository.delete(findBookById(id));
  }

  private Book findBookById(Long id) {
    if (bookRepository.findOne(id) == null) {
      throw new BookException(
          String.format("Book with that ID doesn't exist in the database: %s", id));
    }
    return bookRepository.findOne(id);
  }
}
```

And when I POST @ localhost:8080/books/1 with `{'price':30.00}` I'm getting this error:

```
    2017-03-07 13:12:11.502  INFO 8327 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:471) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:667) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]

2017-03-07 13:12:14.635  INFO 8327 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-03-07 13:12:38.529  WARN 8327 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of double out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@61fe4c68; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of double out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@61fe4c68; line: 1, column: 1]
2017-03-07 13:12:38.529  WARN 8327 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of double out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@61fe4c68; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of double out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@61fe4c68; line: 1, column: 1]
2017-03-07 13:13:23.069  WARN 8327 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of double out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6e8cb870; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of double out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6e8cb870; line: 1, column: 1]
2017-03-07 13:13:23.069  WARN 8327 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of double out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6e8cb870; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of double out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6e8cb870; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Comment: Not about the question you asked, but if you can use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double newPrice)` without problems, you probably don't need BigDecimal at all...

Comment: Using `BigDecimal` is probably an overkill. The reason you get an error on POST is because single quotes is not valid json, you need to use `{"price":30.00}`

Comment: Can you show the setters and getters of bookDTO, probably double values are being sent as string.